# Core Data: attributes in many-to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I'm working on a Core Data based application (I'm used to work with sqlite, but this time I wanted to learn something new) and I'm stuck on this relation problem:

I have Songs and Playlists, and I want to relate them with an order number, so playlists can be like this:

```
 - "Playlist A"   
       1. Song A  
       2. Song C  
       3. Song B
 - "Playlist B" 
       1. Song C  
       2. Song A  
       3. Song B
       4. Song F
       5. Song E
```

This is an obvious many-2-many case, with (i know it's not standard) the order number stored in related table; in sql I'd do

```
  Table  "Songs"  (id, name, ecc..)
  Table  "Playlists" (id,name, ecc..)
  Table  "PlaylistSongs" (playlist_id,song_id,position)

In Core Data i did:
      Entity "Song"
      Entity "Playlist"
      Entity "SongInPlaylist"

with this relation:
  Song <---->> SongInPlaylist
  Playlist <----->> SongInPlaylist
```

But now i don't know how to:

a) put a song in playlist at certain index
b) get songs in a playlist in correct order
c) modify playlist order.

Does anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a SongInPlaylist needs a `position` attribute.  You can then give the PlayList some methods to insert at an index, move from one index to another, or remove at an index which would fix the position values of other SongInPlaylist entities.

Comment: actually i forgot to say that i already put that. What I'm missing is how to create an entry in SongInPlaylist specifying both the Song and the Playlist

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that in any detail without knowing your UI but, basically, your user does something to indicate "put this song at some position in that playlist".  In response, you create a new SongInPlaylist entity and fill in the three fields.  (I'm assuming you have both the song and playlist objects available because you're probably showing them to the user in some way.)

Comment: The other thing...using various ids is normal for direct database programming but in Core Data you're using the entities directly (in case you were thinking you needed actual id fields in your objects).

Comment: Yep in fact is what I was actually missing :) I've finished setting up the relations correctly, then in order to add items i just had to set the Song object and Playlist object in the SongInPlaylist item. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
Song *song = yourSong;
Playlist *playlist = yourPlaylist;
NSNumber *position = songsPositionInPlaylist;

// add song to playlist
SongInPlaylist *sip = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SongInPlaylist" inManagedObjectContext:yourContext];
sip.song = yourSong;
sip.playlist = yourPlaylist;
sip.position = songsPositionInPlaylist;

[yourContext save:nil];
```

Comment: It's exactly what i did after Phillip Mills suggestions, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add an item in the middle, something like "PlaylistEntry", that points to a Song and has a field for order.  Build your play lists out of PlaylistEntries rather than Songs directly. You can then sort on the order field and manipulate it to change the sorting of the Playlist.

Comment: Thank you for answering,  the comment i posted to Philip Mills is  valid for your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is an ideal use for ordered relationships.  Simply check the "Ordered" box in the data model editor, and each play list will hold references to its songs in the order you prescribe.